# Specific php file not opening

Tags: php, file, apache2

hopefully someone can shed some light on my problem. I just reinstalled my OS (lubuntu 12.10) and have set up my local server. Everything seems to be working properly except for the one file I'm currently working on. When I try to run it in the browser, it downloads and/or gives a Server Error (HTTP Error 500).

I don't suppose it's an Apache or PHP problem since other files work just fine, but I don't think there's anything wrong with the code in the file in question.

What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: It's probably a permissions issue. Check and change the permissions if necessary and then restart Apache.

Comment: 500 errors are logged in the server error log, with details as to why it's occuring. what you see in a browser is purposefully useless/pointless to prevent leaking internal details.

Comment: clear the file and run it in your browser, if the problem remain then yes it's not the code

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thank you minitech and  shiplu.mokadd.im. The logs are it. I looked in there and found a few things wrong with my code. Fixed those, and file works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to "suppose" or devise "more than likely" cause or guess "what else".

HTTP Error 500 means there is something verbose in the server's `error_log`.
Just open it end get the exact explanation of the problem.

Please, do not take blind action, out of mere guess. You can make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more then likely caused by a permissions issue.

The Apache server runs as `www-data:www-data`. What this means is that it is possible to have some permission issues with files that were created by another user.

To solve this, you should either add your user to the `www-data` group and set the `/var/www` directory to inherit the group `www-data`, or you can use `chown` to change the ownership of all the files to be on the `www-data` group.

To keep security in your system, you should also make sure that all your files have a permission set of `660`, meaning that the owner and anybody of the user group of the file can both read and write, but any other user will not be able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a php script that does run more than 30 seconds (default) you have to change value of [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) by using [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.